# How do you say "sunburn" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I found *sunfrapo* in PIV, but I can't find any evidence that this term is actually used for “sunburn”. The only examples I can find seem to refer to heat stroke.

(PIV lists both definitions.)

Answer (score 16):

In my practical experience I always heard *sunbruliĝo*.

*sunbruliĝo* is the sunburn on the skin. *sunfrapo* I would understand as the german "Sonnenstich", a kind of heat-stroke. It's a sickness, dizziness kind of thing, caused by heating of the brain skin, or something like that.

Comment: I think that "sunfrapo" is a calque of the French "*coup de soleil*", which is the usual idiom for "sunbruliĝo".

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure that *sunbruno* is actually suntan and *sunbrulo* is sunburn.

*Bruli* is intransitive. I think *brulo* here must refer to the sensation of burning:

- *Mi sunbrulas.* I am sunburnt. (That is, "I am burning on account of the sun.")
- *Mi sunbruliĝas.* I am getting sunburnt.
- *Mi havas sunbrulon.* I have sunburn.

And it would work the same way for *sunbruno*.

More generally, a burn is a *brulvundo* ("burn wound").

*Sunbruliĝo* is "solar combustion", and is awkward to justify here (unless the metaphor is that your skin has "caught fire"). In any case *sunvundo* would probably be a better term (*Mi sunvundiĝis*, etc.)

Comment: Is there a term in actual use, though? Of course, I thought of the literal "sunbruno" but it's not listed in PIV and not used in tekstaro.com.

Comment: I just checked Wells's dictionary and the entry for the English word *tan* is consistent with my examples: *(sun)brun-igi, -iĝi, -o*.

Comment: Perhaps I could have worded my question more clearly, but I was trying to ask about actual usage, not necessarily what's proposed in dictionaries.  In Krause there's _sunbrulumo_ - but it's not clear whether that one is in actual use either.

And I made a typo in my previous comment. I meant that _sunbrulo_ is not listed in PIV. _Sunbruno_ certainly is.

Answer (score 5):

JC Wells in his Esperanto Dictionary translates it as *sunbruno*, and, as you suggest, *sunfrapo* is a sunstroke.

Comment: _Sunbruno_ would be "sun tan", wouldn't it? That's what PIV seems to be suggesting.

Comment: Wells uses the same word for both, probably because he's English. :)  But yes, it should really be 'sun tan', and perhaps _sunbrulo_ for a sunburn.